# How do I look for folders which have .c files along with Makefile ? I want the names or contents of the folders

Tags: files, find, directory

I have certain folders which have both .c and Makefile in them. I need to know which folders have this. What command do I type in linux to find these folders?

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
has() ()(($#)) $REPLY/$~1(N)

ls -- **/*(/e{has Makefile}e{has \\*.c})
```

`has` there is defined as a function that checks whether the glob given as argument resolves to any file in the `$REPLY` directory. We use that function in the `e` glob qualifier to decide whether the directories are selected. Some of the zsh features in there:

- `() {compound-command} arguments`: anonymous function. Here the code of that function is `(($#))`, which returns true if the number of arguments is non-zero
- `$~1`: `zsh` doesn't split+glob by default upon parameter expansion. You have to request it explicitly `$~1` is to request the *glob* part upon the expansion of `$1`, that is for `$1` to be taken as a pattern.
- `(N)`: glob qualifier that enables *nullglob* for that one glob, that is tell the glob to expand to nothing if it doesn't match any file.
- `**/`: any level of subdirectories
- `(/e...)`: another glob qualifier, where `/` matches only on files of type *directory*, and `e{code}` that matches for files for which the *code* resolves to true (with the file stored in `$REPLY`).

Add some `D` glob qualifiers if you want to look into hidden dirs and consider hidden `c` files:

```
printf '%s\n' **/*(D/e{has Makefile}e{'has "*.c(#qD)"'})
```

With GNU tools:

```
LC_ALL=C find . \( -name '*.c' -o -name Makefile \) -print0 |
   LC_ALL=C awk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' '
     {dirname = $0; sub("/[^/]*$", "", dirname)}
     /\.c$/ {hasc[dirname]; next}
     {hasMakefile[dirname]}
     END {for (dir in hasc) if (dir in hasMakefile) print dir}' |
   xargs -r0 ls
```

If you want to not descend into hidden dirs, and not consider hidden C files, change the `find` command to:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '.?*' -prune -o \( -name '*.c' -o -name Makefile \) -print0
```

Those would give the path and content of the matching directories, but if there's only one matching directory, `ls` will not output its path. You can replace `ls --` with `printf '%s\n'` if you only want the paths of the matching directories.

Comment: (only one directory, or argmax-size group(s) with one left over)

Answer (score 1):

Not a serious answer, but problems like this sometimes make we wish for SQL-in-shell, or perhaps the opposite, something like:

```
 find . -type f |
 awk -F/ -vOFS=/ -vq=\' 'BEGIN{print "create table temp (dir varchar, f varchar);"}
      {f=$(NF--); print "insert into temp values(" q $0 q "," q f q ");" }
      END{print "select dir from temp group by dir ";
           print "having sum(when f like "q"%.c"q" then 1 else 0 end)>0 ";
           print "and sum(when f="q"Makefile"q" then 1 else 0 end)=1;"}
      ' | dosql
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU find, we can do it as:

```
find . -type f -name Makefile \
-execdir sh -c '
   find . ! -name . -prune -name \*.c -execdir pwd \; -quit
' \;
```

Wherein we are first looking at finding regular files named Makefile and then using the directory where they are to be found, launch a sh which shall launch a find only to find .c files in that directory and printing the dir name upon finding the first .c and then promptly quitting.